# How to pass data back to the first view controller in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have two view controllers and I have this code to navigate between the  two views

```
ViewController:
func goToSecondViewController() {
  let aa = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as SecondViewController
  self.navigationController.pushViewController(aa, animated: true)
}
```

/

```
SecondViewController:
func goToFirstViewController() {
  self.navigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

How to send some data to the first view before popping it ?

Answer (score 4):

If A is a view controller with the following declaration:

```
class A : UIViewController {
   var data: String!
}
```

Then, whenever you have an instance of A, you can just set the data property directly:

```
let a = A() // assuming you've defined the init method
a.data = "hello"
```

#### Edit

If you want to send data before popping, you'd do something like:

```
func goToFirstViewController() {
  let a = self.navigationController.viewControllers.first as! A
  a.data = "data"
  self.navigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

(haven't compiled the above)

Comment: hello 
it shows compilation error on ((firstObject))
" '[AnyObject]' does not have a member named 'firstObject' "

Comment: `let a = self.navigationController.viewControllers.first as! A`

Comment: I am doing exactly same that you have done but I am calling `self.navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)` instead of `popToRoot` what shold i do that